# Correct folder for injection class in Slim

Tags: php, class, slim

I have one routing to a class that implements “Action”.
So I placed it in the src\Application\Actions folder.

Also have another routing to a class, but this class does not implement no interface. I use __invoke.

Which is the propper folder for this class in the Slim structure to be placed in?
I’m new to Slim

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Slim has an structure of folders that has semantic meaning for example "Action" implemented classe are in the folder  I especified.
But I have created another entrypoint controller which is not implementing "Action" or any interface or class.
There is one answer that said that anyway  I should placed there anyway.
I'm new trying to respect the most Slim philosofy.

Answer (score 0):

I would place it on `src/Application/Actions`.

[Slim Skeleton](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton) is a good inspiration for structure.

Comment: Ok, thanks  I'm trying to respect the most of Slim philosofy about the placement in the skeleton. 
Thanks